# crystal report not showing only 1 field data else show correct

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            cryinvoice rpt = new cryinvoice();
            //The report you created.
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter myDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            //The DataSet you created.
            con = new OleDbConnection(cn);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  Invoice.*,ProductSold.*,Customer.* FROM Invoice,Customer,ProductSold WHERE (Invoice.invoiceID = ProductSold.invoiceID) AND (Invoice.cusomerID = Customer.CustomerID) AND (Invoice.invoiceID = 'INV-83351351')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
            myDA.Fill(myDS, "Invoice");
            //myDA.Fill(myDS, "");
            myDA.Fill(myDS, "ProductSold");
            myDA.Fill(myDS, "Customer");
            rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
            Forminvoiveinfo frm = new Forminvoiveinfo();
            frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            frm.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

In Image,u show invoiceID field bound then not show data of invoiceID why?
I also tri new report but in this same error not show only invoiceID?

Comment: well in the line where you have `rpt.SetDataSource(myDS)` I think since it's a dataset and you need to get at the actual table(s) in that dataset
`rpt.SetDataSource(MyDS.Tables[0]);` try that

Comment: but 3 tables as datasource...and invoice date is display..only invoiceID not display in same table Invoice

Comment: rpt.SetDataSource(MyDS.Tables[0]); I try it but no data display of any table

Comment: do you know how to use the debugger and the QuickWatch ..? I think you should step thru the code and try to pinpoint what you are missing.. it's not really clear what's in regards to what you are seeing and what you are not seeing..perhaps it could be as simple as one of the datafieds in the report is incorrect or spelled wrong or looking at a different field than expected.. did you check all the reports in the designer..?